# Flying Saucer - Open an attachment from pdf link

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I would like to know if there is a way to create a link (Using HTML) to open an attachment embedded in the pdf document.

Something like this...

```
<a href="attachment.pdf">Open the attachment file</a> or <a href="file:///attachment.pdf">Open the attachment file</a>
```

[image]

Any suggestion or recommendation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to implement this scenario after reading the next useful post

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flying-saucer-users/KuwPoTjaQYU

Steps:

1. Check out the next repository https://github.com/osnard/flyingsaucer
2. Analyse the file [ITextOutputDevice.java](https://github.com/osnard/flyingsaucer/blob/master/flying-saucer-pdf/src/main/java/org/xhtmlrenderer/pdf/ITextOutputDevice.java), method **processLink(RenderingContext c, Box box)**
3. Make changes based on your needs
4. Build the project and use the jar file generated

Here the code to create an embedded file based on base64 content.

**Java**

```
...String doEmbedFile = handler.getAttributeValue( elem, "data-fs-embed-file" );
    if ("true".equals(doEmbedFile.toLowerCase())) {
        String fileName = new File(uri).getName();
        String content = handler.getAttributeValue( elem, "content" );

        com.lowagie.text.Rectangle targetArea = checkLinkArea(c, box);
        if (targetArea == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (!_attachments.contains(fileName)) {
                byte[] fileBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(content.getBytes("UTF-8")); 
                PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(_writer, null, fileName, fileBytes);
                fs.addDescription(fileName, true);
                _writer.addFileAttachment(fs);
                _attachments.add(fileName);
            }
            targetArea.setBorder(0);
            targetArea.setBorderWidth(0);

            //This only works on Adobe Acrobat Reader
            PdfAction action = PdfAction.javaScript(
                "this.exportDataObject({cName:\"" + fileName + "\", nLaunch:2});",
                _writer
            );...
```

**HTML**

```
<body><div id='div1'><p><a href='test.png' data-fs-embed-file='true' content='iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU...'>open test.png file</a></p></div><div id='div2'><p><a href='test.pdf' data-fs-embed-file='true' content='JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1D...'>open test.pdf file</a></p></div><div id='div3'><p><a href='test.txt' data-fs-embed-file='true' content='VEVFRUVFRUVFRVNUIFRYVA=='>open test.txt file</a></p></div></body>
```

*base64 content truncated

**Output**

[image]

Greetings and I hope it can help others

Answer (score 0):

just open it on new tab, add attribute target="_blank" in your anchor tag

```
<a href="http://link.to/file.pdf" target="_blank">Open attachment</a>
```

Comment: I am looking for the right way to open an embedded file in a pdf document, basically I want to know if flying-saucer library supports this behavior.